# Modify Bootstrap Gallery Modal Animation (by blueimp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery

I am currently using a modal gallery plugin aptly named the [Bootstrap Image Gallery](http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/) by blueimp . I have managed to customize many of it's features so far, but am a bit stumpted on how I would be able to modify the animation that it displays when you click on a new slide. I can see that the script is performing a translateX on the modal window and sets the modal off the screen. Forgive me in advance for asking such a basic question, I am still learning js.

```
<div class="slide" data-index="1" style="width: 1920px; left: -1920px; -webkit-transition: 0ms; transition: 0ms; -webkit-transform: translate(-1920px, 0px) translateZ(0px);"></div>
```

I can't for the life of me see where in this code that the animation is set. I have written a new set of animations that I want to use instead. Thank you so much for your time, I'm excited to hear what you think. :)

- http://jsbin.com/jotezamolo/2/ Here is a Link to a JS bin I made using the stock demo. Fiddle away :).

Here is the base gallery script

```
(function (factory) {
'use strict';
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([
        'jquery',
        './blueimp-gallery'
    ], factory);
} else {
    factory(
        window.jQuery,
        window.blueimp.Gallery
    );
}
}(function ($, Gallery) {
'use strict';

// Global click handler to open links with data-gallery attribute
// in the Gallery lightbox:
$(document).on('click', '[data-gallery]', function (event) {
    // Get the container id from the data-gallery attribute:
    var id = $(this).data('gallery'),
        widget = $(id),
        container = (widget.length && widget) ||
            $(Gallery.prototype.options.container),
        callbacks = {
            onopen: function () {
                container
                    .data('gallery', this)
                    .trigger('open');
            },
            onopened: function () {
                container.trigger('opened');
            },
            onslide: function () {
                container.trigger('slide', arguments);
            },
            onslideend: function () {
                container.trigger('slideend', arguments);
            },
            onslidecomplete: function () {
                container.trigger('slidecomplete', arguments);
            },
            onclose: function () {
                container.trigger('close');
            },
            onclosed: function () {
                container
                    .trigger('closed')
                    .removeData('gallery');
            }
        },
        options = $.extend(
            // Retrieve custom options from data-attributes
            // on the Gallery widget:
            container.data(),
            {
                container: container[0],
                index: this,
                event: event
            },
            callbacks
        ),
        // Select all links with the same data-gallery attribute:
        links = $('[data-gallery="' + id + '"]');
    if (options.filter) {
        links = links.filter(options.filter);
    }
    return new Gallery(links, options);
});

}));
```

Here is the bootstrap extention:

```
/*
 * Bootstrap Image Gallery 3.0.1
 * https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

/*global define, window */

(function (factory) {
'use strict';
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([
        'jquery',
        './blueimp-gallery'
    ], factory);
} else {
    factory(
        window.jQuery,
        window.blueimp.Gallery
    );
}
}(function ($, Gallery) {
'use strict';

$.extend(Gallery.prototype.options, {
    useBootstrapModal: true
});

var close = Gallery.prototype.close,
    imageFactory = Gallery.prototype.imageFactory,
    videoFactory = Gallery.prototype.videoFactory,
    textFactory = Gallery.prototype.textFactory;

$.extend(Gallery.prototype, {

    modalFactory: function (obj, callback, factoryInterface, factory) {
        if (!this.options.useBootstrapModal || factoryInterface) {
            return factory.call(this, obj, callback, factoryInterface);
        }
        var that = this,
            modalTemplate = this.container.children('.modal'),
            modal = modalTemplate.clone().show()
                .on('click', function (event) {
                    // Close modal if click is outside of modal-content:
                    if (event.target === modal[0] ||
                            event.target === modal.children()[0]) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        that.close();
                    }
                }),
            element = factory.call(this, obj, function (event) {
                callback({
                    type: event.type,
                    target: modal[0]
                });
                modal.addClass('in');
            }, factoryInterface);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text(element.title || String.fromCharCode(160));
        modal.find('.modal-body').append(element);
        return modal[0];
    },

    imageFactory: function (obj, callback, factoryInterface) {
        return this.modalFactory(obj, callback, factoryInterface, imageFactory);
    },

    videoFactory: function (obj, callback, factoryInterface) {
        return this.modalFactory(obj, callback, factoryInterface, videoFactory);
    },

    textFactory: function (obj, callback, factoryInterface) {
        return this.modalFactory(obj, callback, factoryInterface, textFactory);
    },

    close: function () {
        this.container.find('.modal').removeClass('in');
        close.call(this);
    }

});

}));
```

Comment: is there a question in this? If it isn't working properly perhaps a demo would help

Comment: Well the code is working perfectly as shown in the link provided. What I am attempting is modifying the animation that is shown when a new slide is triggered. As I said above "I can't for the life of me see where in this code that the animation is set", what I was hoping is someone to be able to assist me in understanding the logic that applies the animation to the modal window.

Comment: numerous resources for demos like jsfiddle.net, plnkr.co , jsbin.com, codepen.io to name a few

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jotezamolo/2/ here is a bin I made of the demo without all the extra modifications that I've made. *channeling Han Solo*